# Large spike in Firestore writes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I troubleshoot a relative massive spike in Firestore writes? I have under 20 users and at a time when when I am not using the app personally there is a spike of 2500 writes within a 1 hour window and there are less than 10 writes prior to the spike and less than 10 writes after the spike. How do I troubleshoot what is causing this spike in writes? I have attached a screenshot of my Firestore usage showing the spike.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently no tools provided to tell you where access to Firestore is coming from, other than what you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage).  You will need to add some logging or debugging to any code that might write a document, then examine its output to find out which writes are unexpected.